# uglifyjs not obfuscating global variable

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I'm using uglifyjs (via grunt) and am trying to get a global variable obfuscated, but it's not working. I'm using the 'toplevel' option with mangle.

Was wondering if anyone could answer why?

Bypassing grunt and using uglify directly, the command-line I'm using is:

```
uglifyjs js/a.js -c -m toplevel -o dist/scripts.js
```

The contents of a.js are:

```
foo = 5;

function bar() {
  var excellent = 10;

  var myvar = excellent*excellent;

  console.log('myvar = ' + myvar);
}

bar();

function useAGlobal() {
  console.log('foo = ' + foo);
}

useAGlobal();
```

and the uglified code is:

```
function o(){var o=10,n=o*o;console.log("myvar = "+n)}function n(){console.log("foo = "+foo)}foo=5,o(),n();
```

I can see the global functions `bar()` and `useAGlobal()` get obfuscated just fine, but why does the variable `foo` remain unchanged?

If I declare `foo` with the 'var' keyword as `var foo = 5;`, then it does get obfuscated. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing `foo = 5` without var it's considered an assignment compared to `var foo = 5` which is a declaration. The reason why assignment variable name doesn't get obfuscated is that it is assuming that it is declared somewhere else outside of the current js in the global scope. In the browser, everything in the global scope is associated with `window`. So if you for example did `location = 'http://www.google.com.au';` it would send your browser to google. If the `location` were to be obfuscated then the code wouldn't function correctly.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect, thanks. Unfortunately we might have some legacy code where 'var' was not used, so I guess those variables won't get obfuscated...but that's life. :-)